# Upgrading spring-security-cas to spring 6.x

Tags: spring, spring-security, java-17, spring-security-cas

I am upgrading a project from Spring 5.x to Spring 6.x. The project uses CAS for Single Sign On. While upgrading the project, I found that the latest version of spring-security-cas is 5.8.1 whereas the latest version of Spring Security is 6.0.1. The *spring-security-cas (5.8.1)* still uses the *javax namespace* which is not compatible with spring 6.x. What should be the correct migration steps to Spring 6 assuming that spring-security-cas needs to be there in the project ?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10441 it has been removed as at that time there was no Java 17 and JakartaEE compatible version. There is still an open ticket for re-adding the support not sure when that is going to happen.

So for now there is no support.

However (as also pointed out in the comments) it is on the list to be added again. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11674

Comment: It's on our list to re-add in the near future! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11674

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

`implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:6.2.1")`